# How to add all the same float values in a list then placing these values in a new list

Tags: python, indexing, floating-point, sum

If I have a list (`listA`) of floats with repeating values, how would I add the same repeating values together and put them in a new list (`listB`)?

For example:

```
listA = [1.356, 7.663, 12.466, 1.356, 7.663, 12.466, 1.356, 7.663, 12.466]
```

The values 1.356, 7.663, 12.466 are repeated 3x.
I would like to add the same values together and put them in a new list:

```
listB = [4.068, 22.989, 37.398]
```

The first value is the sum of all 1.356, the 2nd value sum of 7.663 etc.

Comment: Can I suggest that you show the code you executed along with the output and explain what the output should be?

Comment: I have completely reworded the question as now I can see it was very unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be broken down in two steps:

1. count how often each number occurs
2. multiply each number by how often it occurs and add the result to a list

The first step is what [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) exists for.

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> c = Counter(listA)
>>> c
Counter({1.356: 3, 7.663: 3, 12.466: 3})
```

For the second step, iterate over the (value, count) pairs in `Counter` object by using its [`items`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items) method (inherited from `dict`):

```
>>> listB = []
>>> for value, count in c.items():
...     listB.append(value * count)
...
>>> listB
[4.0680000000000005, 22.989, 37.397999999999996]
```

Or in short:

```
listB = [value * count for value, count in Counter(listA).items()]
```

Comment: Thank you! I have never encountered this method before.

Answer (score 0):

You use a loop that takes each element of the list and checks that it is not among the next values and that it is not already present in the destination list.

In the next cycle you check the following elements again because you have already checked the element you are comparing with the previous ones.

This allows you not to check the previous values because they have already been verified.

```
listA = [1.356, 7.663, 12.466, 1.356, 7.663, 12.466, 1.356, 7.663, 12.466]
listB = []

iterator = 0
for index in listA:
    if index in listA[iterator + 1:]:
        if index not in listB:
            listB.append(index)
    iterator += 1

print(listB)
```

Comment: This is not a minimum of checks. It is O(n^2). Sorting the list would give an O(n log n) algorithm.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Maybe my English is a little rusty. I meant that it avoids checking the previous values because they have already been verified.
I didn't mean that's the best way to do it.
I will modify my answer.